# Row count based on a list of tables in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I am using an `Input Table` step to retrieve a list of owners and tables from Oracle's `ALL_TABLES`, then I want to pass to another step to, for each of this `owner.table` entries, it performs a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM owner.table`.

The final result I want something like:

`OWNER` - `TABLE` - `COUNT`

How could I do that in Pentaho?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the `Group By` step?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why would I use `Group By` in this case?

Comment: Sorry when I first saw the question I thought you wanted a count of tables for that owner. Try the `Execute SQL Script` step instead.

Comment: If that doesn't give you the output you need try the `Dynamic SQL row` step from the Lookup branch.

Comment: Is this question still open?